# Using fonts with Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, font-face, assets

I have some fonts being configured in my Scss file like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Icomoon';
  src: asset-url('icoMoon.eot?#iefix', font) format('embedded-opentype'),
       asset-url('icoMoon.woff', font) format('woff'),
       asset-url('icoMoon.ttf', font)  format('truetype'),
       asset-url('icoMoon.svg#Icomoon', font) format('svg');
}
```

The actual font file are stored in /app/assets/fonts/

I have added `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")` to my application.rb file

and the compile CSS source is as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Icomoon';
  src: url(/assets/icoMoon.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/assets/icoMoon.woff) format("woff"), url(/assets/icoMoon.ttf) format("truetype"), url(/assets/icoMoon.svg#Icomoon) format("svg");
}
```

But when I run the app the font files are not being found. The logs:

> Started GET "/assets/icoMoon.ttf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-05 23:21:17 +0100
>   Served asset /icoMoon.ttf - 404 Not Found (13ms)

Why isn't the asset pipeline flattening the font files down into just /assets?

Any ideas people?

Kind regards,
Neil

**Extra info:**

When checking the rails console for assets paths and assetprecompile I get the following:

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > y Rails.application.config.assets.precompile
---
- !ruby/object:Proc {}
- !ruby/regexp /(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/
- .svg
- .eot
- .woff
- .ttf
=> nil



1.9.2p320 :002 > y Rails.application.config.assets.paths
---
- /Users/neiltonge/code/neiltonge/app/assets/fonts
- /Users/neiltonge/code/neiltonge/app/assets/images
- /Users/neiltonge/code/neiltonge/app/assets/javascripts
- /Users/neiltonge/code/neiltonge/app/assets/stylesheets
- /Users/neiltonge/code/neiltonge/vendor/assets/images
- /Users/neiltonge/code/neiltonge/vendor/assets/javascripts
- /Users/neiltonge/code/neiltonge/vendor/assets/stylesheets
- /Users/neiltonge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@neiltonge/gems/jquery-rails-2.0.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
- /Users/neiltonge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@neiltonge/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.1/lib/assets/javascripts
- /Users/neiltonge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@neiltonge/gems/bourbon-1.3.0/app/assets/stylesheets
- !ruby/object:Pathname
  path: /Users/neiltonge/code/neiltonge/app/assets/fonts
 => nil
```

Comment: You have `font-url` helper in SCSS in Rails.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference unfortunately.  Therefore my question still stands

Comment: I wrote a generic way to diagnose and solve this problem at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40898227/1197775.

Comment: See my answer. You need a few more steps. (rename your css into css.scss, use font-for, edit your initialiser for assets and also run  rails assets:precompile when deploying etc).

Answer (score 669, accepted):

1. If your Rails version is between `> 3.1.0` and `< 4`, place your fonts in any of the these folders:

   - `app/assets/fonts`
   - `lib/assets/fonts`
   - `vendor/assets/fonts`

   For Rails versions `> 4`, you **must** place your fonts in the  `app/assets/fonts` folder.

   **Note:** To place fonts outside of these designated folders, use the following configuration:

   `config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/`

   For Rails versions `> 4.2`, it is **recommended** to add this configuration to `config/initializers/assets.rb`.

   However, you can also add it to either `config/application.rb` , or to `config/production.rb`
2. Declare your font in your CSS file:

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'Icomoon';
     src:url('icomoon.eot');
     src:url('icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg'),
       url('icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
       url('icomoon.ttf') format('truetype');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
   }
   ```

   Make sure your font is named exactly the same as in the URL portion of the declaration. Capital letters and punctuation marks matter. In this case, the font should have the name `icomoon`.
3. If you are using Sass or Less with Rails `> 3.1.0` (your CSS file has `.scss` or `.less` extension), then change the `url(...)` in the font declaration to `font-url(...)`.

   Otherwise, your CSS file should have the extension `.css.erb`, and the font declaration should be `url('<%= asset_path(...) %>')`.

   If you are using Rails `> 3.2.1`, you can use `font_path(...)` instead of `asset_path(...)`. This helper does exactly the same thing but it's more clear.
4. Finally, use your font in your CSS like you declared it in the `font-family` part. If it was declared capitalized, you can use it like this:

   ```
   font-family: 'Icomoon';
   ```

Comment: and unfortunately, neither did this. I'm really confused.

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: Yep, This is why i'm really confused! Can't think of anything else that could be causing it. The compiled url in the css source is pointing to /assets/fontname  but the font file itself just can;t be located at that directory. It seems like the asset pipeline just isn;t flattening them down into just /assets as it should be.

Comment: Perfect.Working perfectly now. Just altered the @font-face syntax to use font-url and all is great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I'm reading **[the source](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/blob/master/lib/less/rails/helpers.rb#L35)** correctly, then Less also has the `font-url(...)` helper! In any case, you could always give your css file the extensions `.less.erb` and then you'd be able to use the previously mentioned trick `url('<%= asset_path(...) %>')`.

Comment: for me, the naming convention of fontname and respective file names was the issue. Really took my 30+hrs and i was ignoring this convention each time

Comment: I had to remove the configs set in step 2 in order for this to work on my setup. I guess sass-rails does the needed magic.

Comment: @NadeemYasin Thanks for your comment, I had the same problem. The file names had hypens in them and when I removed that the solutions proposed here worked.

Comment: font-url didn't work for me, I had to use asset_path .  I suspect it's because of the anchors like #iefix at the end - font-url would compile down to url(...), but leave out the quotes around the filename.

Comment: `config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )` is actually wrong, you need to add to precompile something that matches the full asset name. A regexp worked for me: `config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/`

Comment: Well, the way it is now works for me. So either that line of code is not needed at all or the way to set this config depends on the Rails version (or something else). @Jim had already said that he had to remove the configs on step 2 so maybe we're missing something here. Man, it should be simpler to use fonts with the asset pipeline.

Comment: Step 2 should be removed. According to [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#search-paths), `config.assets.paths` is for Sprockets references, not relevant here. `config.assets.precompile` is also useless because _"The default matcher for compiling files includes application.js, application.css and **all non-JS/CSS files** (this will include all image assets automatically) from app/assets folders"_ (see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets))

Comment: `config.assets.paths` is relevant for [coding links to assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets). As for `config.assets.precompile`, it can be still needed in Rails 3. Compare the [Rails 4 guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) to the [Rails 3 guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets). However, since the way I used precompile is wrong (as people have pointed out), maybe it's not really needed.

Comment: @Ashitaka I also discovered that restarting my server was the trick!

Comment: Also make sure the scaffold.css.scss (if you have one) isn't overriding things with its font declarations.

Comment: @Alex: because %w() returns an array of strings and `precompile` accepts strings only for *full* paths, not partial matches.

Comment: I'm using .scss extension and the font-url trick, I cleared my browser cache and restarted my server, but my css kept requesting `fonts/myfontname.ttf` instead of `assets/...`, where I know the font is actually compiling to. No scaffolds.css.scss file. I even tried `rake assets:clobber` but got no effect, **until** I restarted my server a second time (after the command). It worked! Thanks!

Comment: In step 2, why is there two `src:` properties declared, rather than once with all of the files comma-separated? Does it matter?

Comment: I don't know the exact details, because that `@font-face` syntax comes straight from IcoMoon's app, but here's a [CSS Tricks blog post that kind of covers it](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).

Comment: Looks like there might still be some confusion about this, maybe it also matters which `Rails.env` you are in. In development, I can confirm that with Rails 4.2, and using `sass-rails` 5.0.1, I needed to use `asset-url` rather than `font-url` in the `.scss` file to get a `/assets/` absolute path in my CSS, and I did *not* need to add `fonts/` to my `config.assets.path`

Comment: It is important to note that you must name your file with the extension `.css.scss` -  `.scss` may work for everything else, but will not work here.

Comment: We recently migrated an app from Rails 3 to 4, and needed fonts from an engine to digest properly with the asset pipeline. The accepted answer works fine, but should be using `font-path` (or `font-url`) helpers instead of hardcoding the path in.

Comment: @Ashitaka
I have kind of similar problem but nothing worked
I put a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884226/fonts-issue-in-productions-envirnment-rails?noredirect=1#comment61333640_36884226 , have a look please

Comment: Prior to seeing this answer I spent at least 3 hours to solve this problem... Thank you man!..

Comment: This is by far the best answer!

Answer (score 39):

Now here's a twist:

> You should place all fonts in `app/assets/fonts/` as they **WILL** get precompiled in staging and production by default—they will get precompiled when pushed to *heroku*.
>
> Font files placed in `vendor/assets` will **NOT** be precompiled on staging or production by default — they will fail on *heroku*. [Source!](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7968)

— [@plapier, thoughtbot/bourbon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/239#issuecomment-26167073)

> I strongly believe that putting vendor fonts into `vendor/assets/fonts`
>   makes a lot more sense than putting them into `app/assets/fonts`. With
>   these 2 lines of extra configuration this has worked well for me (on
>   Rails 4):

```
app.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'fonts')  
app.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
```

— [@jhilden, thoughtbot/bourbon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/239#issuecomment-30830589)

I've also tested it on `rails 4.0.0`. Actually the last one line is enough to safely precompile fonts from `vendor` folder. Took a couple of hours to figure it out. Hope it helped someone.

Comment: +1 http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization explains the layout of the asset pipeline and helps understand how this works. Correct as of 2014-07-04

Comment: Do you need both of these? `app.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'fonts')`  
`app.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/` A comment on another answer says the latter takes care of both.

Comment: Even in Rails 4.2+-land, I really think that `app/assets` input to sprockets and friends processed as output `public/assets`, whereas `vendor/assets` can still be useful to deploy assets without modification; both have their use-cases.  The whole convention of vendoring is premised on the guarantee that nothing will happen to `vendor/*`.  (Yes, `vendor/plugins` was abused with code-hoarding, closed-source mania pre gem era and folks just copy-pasted unversioned js into `vendor/assets/javascripts` pre-bower/rails-assets.)

Comment: For those wondering; throw this in `config/initializers/assets.rb`

Answer (score 25):

You need to use `font-url` in your @font-face block, not `url`

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Inconsolata';
src:font-url('Inconsolata-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

as well as this line in application.rb, as you mentioned (for fonts in `app/assets/fonts`

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Comment: you also need to enable precompilation for production

Comment: On a brand new rails 4.2 app, both `src: url(someFont.ttf)` and `src: font-url(someFont.ttf)` worked when having files in `app/assets/fonts`. I have `.scss` extensions by default. I did not need to add to the config.assets.paths.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to keep track of moving your fonts around:

```
# Adding Webfonts to the Asset Pipeline
config.assets.precompile << Proc.new { |path|
  if path =~ /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff)\z/
    true
  end
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution; unless you authored the fonts they probably belong in /vendor/assets/fonts -- not /app/assets/fonts. This approach solves for both, the above does not

Comment: @Casey: this solution does let you put fonts inside vendor/assets.

@Nathan Colgate: This can be simplified to: `config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/`

Comment: @Sunny - I know, that's why I think it's better than the accepted answer

Comment: Also you should end your regex with \Z -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577653/difference-between-a-z-and-in-ruby-regular-expressions

Comment: How do you deal with the hashes that Rails appends to the font file?

Comment: Note that this will also not precompile actual svg image/artwork files, which may be a bad thing...

Comment: @Sunny, so doing also takes care of adding paths as well as enabling precompiling?

Comment: @gwho: This adds these file names to the list of precompileable paths. As for precompiling you still need to call it when you deploy with `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: oh so registering paths and registering it to be available for precompilation weren't two different things.

Answer (score 12):

Here my approach to using fonts in asset pipeline:

1) Put all your font file under `app/assets/fonts/`, actually you are not restricted to put it under `fonts` folder name. You can put any subfolder name you like. E.g. `app/assets/abc` or `app/assets/anotherfonts`. But i highly recommend you put it under `app/assets/fonts/` for better folder structure.

2) From your sass file, using the sass helper `font-path` to request your font assets like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url(font-path('fontawesome-webfont.eot') + '?v=4.4.0');
    src: url(font-path('fontawesome-webfont.eot') + '?#iefix&v=4.4.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(font-path('fontawesome-webfont.woff2') + '?v=4.4.0') format('woff2'),
         url(font-path('fontawesome-webfont.woff') + '?v=4.4.0') format('woff'),
         url(font-path('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') + '?v=4.4.0') format('truetype'),
         url(font-path('fontawesome-webfont.svg') + '?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

3) Run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` from your local machine and see your application.css result. You should see something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont-d4f5a99224154f2a808e42a441ddc9248ffe78b7a4083684ce159270b30b912a.eot" "?v=4.4.0");
    src: url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont-d4f5a99224154f2a808e42a441ddc9248ffe78b7a4083684ce159270b30b912a.eot" "?#iefix&v=4.4.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont-3c4a1bb7ce3234407184f0d80cc4dec075e4ad616b44dcc5778e1cfb1bc24019.woff2" "?v=4.4.0") format("woff2"), url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont-a7c7e4930090e038a280fd61d88f0dc03dad4aeaedbd8c9be3dd9aa4c3b6f8d1.woff" "?v=4.4.0") format("woff"), url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont-1b7f3de49d68b01f415574ebb82e6110a1d09cda2071ad8451bdb5124131a292.ttf" "?v=4.4.0") format("truetype"), url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont-7414288c272f6cc10304aa18e89bf24fb30f40afd644623f425c2c3d71fbe06a.svg" "?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If you want to know more how asset pipeline work, you can visit the following simple guide:
https://designcode.commandrun.com/rails-asset-pipeline-simple-guide-830e2e666f6c#.6lejlayk2

Answer (score 7):

Here is a repo the demonstrates serving a custom font with Rails 5.2 that works on Heroku. It goes further and optimizes serving the fonts to be as fast as possible according to https://www.webpagetest.org/

https://github.com/nzoschke/edgecors

To start I picked pieces from answers above. For Rails 5.2+ you shouldn't need extra asset pipeline config.

### Asset Pipeline and SCSS

- Place fonts in `app/assets/fonts`
- Place the `@font-face` declaration in an scss file and use the `font-url` helper

From `app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.scss`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata';
  src: font-url('Inconsolata-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  font-family: "Inconsolata";
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

#### Serve from CDN with CORS

I'm using CloudFront, added with the [Heroku Edge addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/edge).

First configure a CDN prefix and default `Cache-Control` headers in `production.rb`:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # e.g. https://d1unsc88mkka3m.cloudfront.net
  config.action_controller.asset_host = ENV["EDGE_URL"]

  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=31536000'
  }
end
```

If you try to access the font from the herokuapp.com URL to the CDN URL, you will get a CORS error in your browser:

> Access to font at 'https://d1unsc88mkka3m.cloudfront.net/assets/Inconsolata-Regular.ttf' from origin 'https://edgecors.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. edgecors.herokuapp.com/
>   GET https://d1unsc88mkka3m.cloudfront.net/assets/Inconsolata-Regular.ttf net::ERR_FAILED

So configure CORS to allow access to the font from Heroku to the CDN URL:

```
module EdgeCors
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Deflater

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins %w[
          http://edgecors.herokuapp.com
          https://edgecors.herokuapp.com
        ]
        resource "*", headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### Serve gzip Font Asset

The asset pipeline builds a `.ttf.gz` file but doesn't serve it. This monkey patch changes the asset pipeline gzip whitelist to a blacklist:

```
require 'action_dispatch/middleware/static'

ActionDispatch::FileHandler.class_eval do
  private

    def gzip_file_path(path)
      return false if ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'].include? content_type(path)
      gzip_path = "#{path}.gz"
      if File.exist?(File.join(@root, ::Rack::Utils.unescape_path(gzip_path)))
        gzip_path
      else
        false
      end
    end
end
```

The ultimate result is a custom font file in `app/assets/fonts` served from a long-lived CloudFront cache.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this problem on Rails 4.2 (with ruby 2.2.3) and had to edit the font-awesome _paths.scss partial to remove references to `$fa-font-path` and removing a leading forward slash. The following was broken:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=#{$fa-version}');
  src: font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=#{$fa-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
    font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff2'),
    font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff'),
    font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=#{$fa-version}') format('truetype'),
    font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=#{$fa-version}#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And the following works:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: font-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=#{$fa-version}');
  src: font-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=#{$fa-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
    font-url('fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff2'),
    font-url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff'),
    font-url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=#{$fa-version}') format('truetype'),
    font-url('fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=#{$fa-version}#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

An alternative would be to simply remove the forward slash following the interpolated `$fa-font-path` and then define `$fa-font-path` as an empty string or subdirectory with trailing forward slash (as needed).

Remember to recompile assets and restart your server as needed. For example, on a passenger setup:

```
prompt> rake assets:clean; rake assets:clobber
prompt> RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets rake assets:precompile
prompt> service passenger restart
```

Then reload your browser.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Rails 4.2, and could not get the footable icons to show up.  Little boxes were showing, instead of the (+) on collapsed rows and the little sorting arrows I expected.  After studying the information here, I made one simple change to my code:  remove the font directory in css.  That is, change all the css entries like this:

```
src:url('fonts/footable.eot');
```

to look like this:

```
src:url('footable.eot');
```

It worked.  I think Rails 4.2 already assumes the font directory, so specifying it again in the css code makes the font files not get found.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you try to asset:precompile and then run this in production?.My guess this will only work in dev mode (and not after the assets precompile has run for production)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when I upgraded my Rails 3 app to Rails 4 recently. My fonts were not working properly as in the Rails 4+, we are only allowed to keep the fonts under `app/assets/fonts` directory. But my Rails 3 app had a different font organization. So I had to configure the app so that it still works with Rails 4+ having my fonts in a different place other than `app/assets/fonts`. I have tried several solutions but after I found [non-stupid-digest-assets](https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets) gem, it just made it so easy.

Add this gem by adding the following line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'non-stupid-digest-assets'
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

And finally add the following line in your **config/initializers/non_digest_assets.rb** file:

```
NonStupidDigestAssets.whitelist = [ /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/ ]
```

That's it. This solved my problem nicely. Hope this helps someone who have encountered similar problem like me.

Comment: This answer adds a gem for no reason. The default asset pipeline is fine. You just need to extend the app/initialisers/assets.rb (see my answer). Also you lose the ability to update the font once this is deployed to production (no digest)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the original question was using `asset-url` without results instead of plain `url` css property. Using `asset-url` ended up working for me in Heroku. Plus setting the fonts in `/assets/fonts` folder and calling `asset-url('font.eot')` without adding any subfolder or any other configuration to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file called scaffolds.css.scss, then there's a chance that's overriding all the custom things you're doing in the other files. I commented out that file and suddenly everything worked. If there isn't anything important in that file, you might as well just delete it!

Answer (score 1):

Put your font files (woff, woff2, eot, ttf, ...) in /app/assets/fonts directory.

Then add following to your config/initializers/assets.rb :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)\z/
```

In above answers woff2 was not included (and for future ref, you might need to add other extensions by just adding a |{font-file-extension} here)

Using the font in you css file:

**Important you need to rename it from stylesheet.css into stylesheet.css.scss** (this for the font-url to do its work and transform the url of the font in production correctly after asset precompile):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont'
  src: font-url('myfont.woff') format('woff');
}

body{
  font-family: 'MyFont'
}
```

And then run:

```
rails assets:precompile
```

After running assets precompile your font file is copied from **app/assets/fonts/myfont.woff** into the **public/assets/myfont-{SOME_DIGEST_KEY}.woff** location. And now the above css just works also in production much like image assets.

You can also see that after the precompile assets command an application-{somedigest}.css is created and inside you will see
the @font-face but there our **font-url('myfont.woff')** will be transformed into **url(/assets/myfont.woff-{SOME_DIGEST_KEY}.woff**) now and the digest matches the one that the file was moved to. That way updating your font files also bust the browser cache properly etc.

Make sure your nginx is also serving the public/assets folder for better performance. This was tested with rails 5 and rails 6 in production. It should also work with rails 4 most likely.

Answer (score -7):

just place your fonts inside app/assets/fonts folder and set the autoload path when app start using writing the code in application.rb

**config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")**
and

then  use the following code in css.

@font-face {

```
 font-family: 'icomoon';
 src: asset-url('icomoon.eot');
 src: asset-url('icomoon.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
      asset-url('icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
      asset-url('icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
      asset-url('icomoon.svg') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
```

}

Give it a try.

Thanks

Comment: How does this add anything over the existing answers?