# Is it possible in Rails/Asset pipeline compress several SVGs to one file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, svg, asset-pipeline, sprockets

As you know you can compress several CSS files to one (or JS files). I was wondering if it's possible to compress several SVG to one external file, so the server makes just one request

Basically SVG files are just XML text so it's theoretically possible, however there is a catch how to render several of those images on different places

I'm just wondering

Comment: ..possibly, I can just render my SVG sources as part of my main HTML but still would  be nice if it's external file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for answer but in the end I ended up doing it like this:

In my case I wanted to use my SVG as a background image of div tag so I don't needed to precompile SVGs, I just put the compress format directly to `background-image: url('here')`

so for multiple SVG background:

```
width: 600px:
height: 400px:
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml ...first svg '), url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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')
```

check it here: http://codepen.io/equivalent/full/ymefJ

raw svg format:

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <polyline fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" points="538.5,333.56956481933594 322.25,278.28478240966797 106,223 " id="svg_3"/>
  <ellipse transform="translate(-402 -120)" ry="105" rx="140" id="svg_1" cy="290" cx="745" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

editor: http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html

I believe that the link in  [Tom Harrison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705429/473040) answer is on to something and from what I saw it might work, but I didn't try it myself. So if you want to truly precompile SVG with assets pipeline I encourage you to use that tactic.

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer to this question, which describes how to configure the filetypes the Asset Pipeline will manage: [Using fonts with Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline) (despite the title, it applies to more than fonts).