# style.css.erb precompile assets gives undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have created one file for the fonts in the stylesheets folder in rails application

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'MuseoSans500';
 src: url("<%= asset_path('museosans_500-webfont.eot?')%>") format('embedded-opentype');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 }

@font-face {
 font-family: 'MuseoSans500';
 src: url("<%= asset_path('museosans_500-webfont.woff')%>") format('woff'),
   url("<%= asset_path('museosans_500-webfont.ttf')%>") format('truetype'),
   url("<%= asset_path('museosans_500-webfont.svg#MuseoSans500')%>") format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Now When I precompile the assets .. It gives me error on the style.css.erb page. 
I have kept trace on the sprockets for the path and I got this file. 
The error is

```
paths  subpath /home/new_app/app/assets/stylesheets/app-theme/themes/default/style.css.erb
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

(in /home/hbror/applications/survey/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your fonts in a new asset directory, for example `app/assets/fonts` and include it in asset directories by placing this in your `application.rb`:

```
# Add the fonts path
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')

# Precompile additional assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

Then it should work fine.

Comment: I have already Added these paths in the application.rb as per this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: Then you have a problem in `styles.css.erb`. Try to prefix it like this: `styles.css.scss.erb` to add sass capabilities. Can we see how your `styles.css.erb` looks like?

Comment: I have change it with styles.css now. And added links on the that with  `"<%= asset_path('museosans_500-webfont.ttf')%>"` to `/assets/museosans_500-webfont.ttf` and after that I compile and it works now.