# Rails - 4 Custom Asset Path added in application.rb without restart

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-face, assets

**Rails-4**

For font face mentioned below,

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Verdana";src: url(/assets/Verdana.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

Location of file is **app/assets/fonts** (loaded by rails itself)

Now if I have this file in **app/assets/fonts/client_4** folder,

I had to add following in application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts', 'client_4')
```

or

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts/**/").each do |path|
  config.assets.paths << path
end
```

It worked with font-face url provided as url(/assets/Verdana.ttf), but need to restart server to load application.rb

**Query**

Case is my font file is uploaded by user and stored in newly created  client_x folder present in app/assets/fonts directory.

I want to add asset_path in this case for that client_x folder without restarting server. Please suggest.

**Update**

I added following in controller whenever directory is created,

```
MyApplication::Application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts', "client_#{@client.id}/").to_s
```

And I checked following in page by erb tag,

```
= puts MyApplication::Application.config.assets.paths.inspect
```

And I got following output,

```
[
[ 0] "/home/..../app/assets/fonts",
[ 1] "/home/..../app/assets/images",
[ 2] "/home/..../app/assets/javascripts",
[ 3] "/home/..../app/assets/stylesheets",
[ 4] "/home/..../vendor/assets/javascripts",
.
.
[20] "/home/..../app/assets/fonts/client_164/",
[21] "/home/..../app/assets/fonts/client_163/"
```

]

1. 20th path is added by application.rb & loaded when server started, I do get font file by asset_url in font-face
2. 21st path is added by controller and & I do not get font file by asset_url in font-face.

I am not getting if I inspect I can see both path in assets , still I do not get asset url for font files inside client_163 added by controller. I want it without restarting server. Please suggest if eagerload or autoload can help.

Comment: Restarting the server is necessary to reflect the changes as the *config* is changed.

Comment: @Pavan I checked Application.config.assets.paths before & after starting server where if I push any path, it gets in asset path though controller, It does take it in path but do not reflect when asked for asset_url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get exact what I wanted but I found alternative to work with.

I did not add asset path for sub-directories inside app/assets/fonts/.

I worked with complete url like "#{APP_URL}/assets/client_#{client_id}/#{self[file]}"
which produce url like 'http://localhost:3000/assets/client_163/GreatVibes-Regular.otf'

Here APP_URL for development is, 'http://localhost:3000' set in development.rb.
Similarly added for staging & production.

Better to keep variable APP_URL in application.yml (implementing figaro gem) & accessing as "#{ENV[APP_URL]}" (note: add application.yml in .gitignore)

Waiting for better approach.

**Update**

In staging & production I am getting font applied for *not secure* <s>https</s> url so, please help.