# Glyphicon not showing in Heroku(it was normal before)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, glyphicons

I have a rails 4 application and everything was working fine, until now, instead of the bootstrap glyphicon it appears only a square! I don't know why, I didn't change anything... I want a solution DIFFERENT FROM `changing config.assets.precompile = true, once it is not a good practice and your application will run slowly if you do it.(See [config.assets.compile=true in Rails production, why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not)). Thanks!

Comment: Have you run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production?` and after that commit your changes and push them?

Comment: I run this code and get this error _Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that c:/Users/Osni/desktop/projeto/l
og/production?.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the
 output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed._

Comment: no `?` question mark, sorry just `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't compile your assets locally, heroku tried to compile them but it failed.
That is called slug compilation.

The solution is to compile your files locally, and commit the `public/assets` folder.
To do that you need to run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Why heroku failed compiling your assets? It could be because it detected a `manifest` file into your assets folder, and it assumed that you compiled your assets manually.

Answer (score 3):

Osni, let me explain the issue for you.

--

**Asset Precompilation**

Heroku [precompiles your Rails assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#the-rails-4-asset-pipeline), meaning you need to ensure all the assets are "precompile-proof" before you push them. What I mean by this is when you precompile your assets, Rails [fingerprints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) them (adds hashed value to the end of the filename).

This means that although you may be referencing your assets by their "static" name, your app will not be able to load them as they will have a different name. This is one of the main reasons why [fonts don't work on Heroku for a lot of people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323563/heroku-font-assets-not-working).

When you have custom assets in your stylesheets (such as fonts), you need to ensure several things:

> 1. The assets are referenced correctly inside the stylesheet (use SASS)
> 2. The assets precompile correctly when deployed to Heroku

I would recommend doing the following:

---

**SASS**

Firstly, make sure you reference any dependencies using the [Rails asset path helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) (`asset_path` / `asset_url`):

```
#app/stylesheets/application.css.scss
.test { background: asset_url("your_background_image.png") }
```

This allows you to set the relative file paths, for when you *do* use precompilation. It's the same with your fonts (check [my answer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)); however, you may not have the issue as you're using bootstrap ;)

--

**Precompile**

When you `precompile` your assets, you just need to run:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will take your asset files in the `asset pipeline`, and allow you to use them in your production application on Heroku with no issue

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

**application.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```