# custom font not loading on heroku with rails pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Following this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323563/heroku-font-assets-not-working), I changed all of my `@font-face` definitions to look like the following:

```
  @font-face {
   font-family: 'Pe-icon-7-stroke';
   src:font-url('/assets/Pe-icon-7-stroke.eot?d7yf1v');
   src:font-url('/assets/Pe-icon-7-stroke.eot?#iefixd7yf1v') format('embedded-opentype'),
   font-url('/assets/Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff?d7yf1v') format('woff'),
   font-url('/assets/Pe-icon-7-stroke.ttf?d7yf1v') format('truetype'),
   font-url('/assets/Pe-icon-7-stroke.svg?d7yf1v#Pe-icon-7-stroke') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
  }
```

Where all of the font files are plassed in `/assets/fonts/`.

I also changed the file in which the above `@font-face` is declared from type `.css` to `.scss`. The fonts are still loading in development, but when I added the changes to `git` and pushed to my production site on heroku, the fonts still are not loading.

This may not be indicative of the problem I am having, but when I view my compiled assets on the live site, I see that for the definition of the font, there is written:

```
 font-family:'Pe-icon-7-stroke';
 src:url(/assets/Pe-icon-7-stroke.eot?d7yf1v);
```

as opposed to `font-url` it uses `url` (which is maybe how sass is converted into css, but may also mean that the old application.css is loading?)

https://kaf.herokuapp.com/assets/application-490d8d687dc0c9b526bf1348ca9a3a6f.css

For Reference, here is my complete assets directory on  Github

https://github.com/ebbnormal/kaf/tree/master/app/assets/

Comment: If your css and your fonts are in the same assets directory you don't need to call /assets again, so for example: "Pe-icon-7-stroke.eot" not "/assets/Pe-icon-7-stroke.eot". To go up a directory you'd need to use "../directory above assets" anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> asset-url($relative-asset-path)
>  Returns a url reference to the asset.
>  asset-url("rails.png") returns url(/assets/rails.png)
> ```
>
> As a convenience, for each of the following asset classes there are
>   corresponding -path and -url helpers: 
>   image, font, video, audio,
>   javascript, stylesheet.
>
> - `image-path("rails.png")` returns `"/assets/rails.png"`
> - `image-url("rails.png")` returns `url(/assets/rails.png)`
>
> https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Pe-icon-7-stroke';
     src: font-url('Pe-icon-7-stroke.eot?d7yf1v');
     src: font-url('Pe-icon-7-stroke.eot?#iefixd7yf1v') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       font-url('Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff?d7yf1v') format('woff'),
       font-url('Pe-icon-7-stroke.ttf?d7yf1v') format('truetype'),
       font-url('Pe-icon-7-stroke.svg?d7yf1v#Pe-icon-7-stroke') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Although you might want to consider if you really need all those fallback formats today.

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff

Answer (score 3):

Check out [SASS asset helpers](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#asset-helpers), specifically, this part:

> Returns a url reference to the asset.
>
> `asset-url("rails.png")` returns `url(/assets/rails.png)` As a
>   convenience, for each of the following asset classes there are
>   corresponding `-path` and `-url` helpers: image, font, video, audio,
>   javascript, stylesheet.
>
> `image-path("rails.png")` returns `"/assets/rails.png"`
>   `image-url("rails.png")` returns `url(/assets/rails.png)`

It looks like you need to remove the `/assets` part in your font-url.