# Font files not compiling in production Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hoping for some help. I have a rails project that in production does not seem to be compiling the fonts.

In my application.rb file I have

```
 class Application < Rails::Application
   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
 end
```

With the fonts being added to my scss file like

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Jaapokki';
   src: asset-url("/assets/Jaapokki-Regular.eot");
   src: asset-url("/assets/Jaapokki-Regular.eot?#iefix") 
   format("embedded-opentype"), asset-url("/assets/Jaapokki-Regular.woff") format("woff"), asset-url("/assets/Jaapokki-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

but I get an error in the chrome development console of

`GET https://mve.herokuapp.com/assets/Jaapokki-Regular.woff net::ERR_ABORTED`

Now this works in development, and I have used a similar set-up when deploying to an aws server. However this app is deployed to heroku which seems to be giving me problems. I guess the first question is how can I check if my fonts are even compiling when pushing to production.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your fonts are in `app/assets/fonts`, you should be able to use `font-url` in your SCSS to automatically generate the correct asset path for each font file:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Jaapokki';
   src: font-url("Jaapokki-Regular.eot");
   src: font-url("Jaapokki-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        font-url("Jaapokki-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
        font-url("Jaapokki-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

See Aaron Gray's answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414154/2076253

Comment: No that didn't seem to do anything when the code has been pushed to production

Comment: I will look at this question thread and see if I can find a work around, thanks!

Comment: Oh wait no I'm a fool! I didn't even realise I had that /assets/ in my css, this worked perfectly thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "raty";
    src: url(asset-path("raty.woff"));
}
```

Comment: To help readers better understand the difference between this and the accepted answer, can you explain the conditions under which your approach would be preferred, and what the differences in behavior might be?