# Including fonts from font squirrel in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, fonts, font-face

I'm having trouble including fonts for my rails app.  I tried following the advice from this post: [Using fonts with Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline), but I'm still confused.

I'm trying to add [this font](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto-slab?filter%5Bclassification%5D=slab%20serif&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=headings&filter%5Bfamily_size%5D=1&filter%5Bdownload%5D=all&sort=popular). I made an `app/assets/fonts` folder and added the fonts to it. I changed `production.rb` accordingly.

I'm confused about declaring my fonts like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Icomoon';
  src:url('icomoon.eot');
  src:url('icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg'),
    url('icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('icomoon.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

These are my 4 RobotoSlab fonts:

- `RobotoSlab-Bold.ttf`
- `RobotoSlab-Light.ttf`
- `RobotoSlab-Regular.ttf`
- `RobotoSlab-Thin.ttf`

They all have dashes in the names.  So what do I write instead of `iconmoon.eot`?  `RobotoSlab-Regular.ttf` or `RobotoSlab.ttf`?

Also, I'm confused about where I should address the `.eot` part, and where I should address the `.ttf` part.  In the example above, the `.eot` part was addressed first, and then the `.ttf` part was addressed along with all the other formats.  But the default extension for my font is `.ttf`, so does that change things?

Also, I'm confused about which font files I'm supposed to include.  Most fonts on http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ have multiple font files to download (in order to address variations of bold and italics).  Are you supposed to link to all of them in `@font-face`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things which could be a problem:

---

**Where are your font files actually stored?**

If they are in `/assets/fonts`, you need to reference that path directly:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Icomoon';
  src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
  src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

---

**Did you use `stylesheet.css` from Font-Squirrel?**

`Stylesheet.css` has all the code for the different fonts you've just turned into @font-face elements. You mentioned you have several fonts which are not included in your css file -- the rendered fonts from front-squirrel will have the relevant code contained in the `stylesheet.css` which comes with them

You just need to change the references in the stylesheet to your own app, and include the code in a `.css` file of your own

Comment: The font files are in `app/assets/fonts`.

That still doesn't answer my questions of 1) Do I include a dash, 2) Where do I use `.eot` vs. `.ttf`, and 3) Which font files should I include.

Comment: I didn't use `stylesheet.css` from Font Squirrel.  I didn't see anything about that.  Even if I used it, I'm not sure how to implement it with Rails, because my css files are all `.css.scss`.