# Official way of adding custom fonts to Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, ruby-on-rails-4, assets, directory-structure

I'm researching how to add custom fonts to my Rails app, e.g. by adding a `fonts` folder in the assets folder - and I cannot find an "official" Rails way on how to do this.

Yes, there are plenty of questions/answers here on SO about the matter, all seemingly with their own hacks. But shouldn't such a common practice go under Rails' famous "convention over configuration"?

**Or if I've missed it - where is the documentation reference on how to organize fonts in a Rails app?**

Comment: there is no mention of fonts in the official doc for asset pipeline - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: complete reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes the link given will explain it well, however if u need another detailed explanation then here it is

- Firstly to use custom fonts in your app you need to download font files, you can try https://www.1001freefonts.com/ and look for fonts

  Few of the most popular font file formats are mainly .otf(Open Type Format) .ttf(True Type Format) .woff(Web Open Font Format)
- You can move the downloaded fonts to your app folder under app/assets/fonts/
- After downloading the file you need to "declare" the fonts you will be using in your css like this

  ```
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Kaushan Script Regular";
    src: url(/assets/KaushanScript-Regular.otf) format("truetype");
  }
  ```
- Finally you can use the font-family that you just declared wherever you want like this

  ```
  #e-registration {
    font-family: "Kaushan Script Regular";
  }
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Outstanding explanation.  In case anyone has any trouble with the specifics.  Under my app, the css `src` line needed to be changed to `src: url(KaushanScript-Regular.otf) format("truetype");`

Comment: Is this all that's necessary? What about adding config paths and making sure it works on production?

Comment: You specify the font format. But when you include multiple types, do you declare multiple lines to fall back on? How do you do that, just declare multiple lines?

Comment: Don't you need to use `asset-url()` so that it works on production when it gets precompiled and a hash digest gets appended to the file name?

Comment: What is the truetype for?

Comment: @Jwan622 - The `format()` is to provide the browser with a hint as to what format a font resource is, so it can select a suitable one. The available types are: `woff`, `woff2`, `truetype`, `opentype`, `embedded-opentype`, and `svg`.

Comment: Add this line to config/application.rb config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"

Answer (score 20):

Just did it...

1. Download and save the font files (eot, woff, woff2...) in your
   **assets/fonts/** directory

   2. In your **config/application.rb** add this line  config.assets.paths
      << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")

What this does is it
    precompiles your fonts folder just as it does by default with your
    images, stylesheets etc.

3. and make sure this line is set to **true**  config.assets.enabled =
   true
4. In your sass/scss or even inline with `<script>` tag

   ```
   @font-face {   font-family: 'Bariol Regular';   src:
   font-url('Bariol_Regular_Webfont/bariol_regular-webfont.eot');  
   src:
   font-url('Bariol_Regular_Webfont/bariol_regular-webfont.eot?iefix')
   format('eot'),  
   font-url('Bariol_Regular_Webfont/bariol_regular-webfont.woff')
   format('woff'),  
   font-url('Bariol_Regular_Webfont/bariol_regular-webfont.ttf')
   format('truetype'),  
   font-url('Bariol_Regular_Webfont/bariol_regular-webfont.svg#webfont3AwWkQXK')
   format('svg');   font-weight: normal;   font-style: normal; }
   ```

Note that you should use the `font-url` helper instead of css' `url` to address the fingerprinting done by Rails when it precompiles the assets

Finally, set the font-family in your CSS files

```
body {
   font-family: 'Bariol Regular', serif;
}
```

FREE TIP:
This being said, the best way in terms of performance is to set this up with JS so that these fonts get loaded asynchronously. Check this loader: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Comment: With Rails 5, I was able to add my fonts to /app/assets/fonts and use the font-url() method when specifying the font src.  This was enough to work, I did not need to change any other configurations (didn't do step 2 or 3 above)

Comment: For me I added this config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"

Answer (score 5):

I had some trouble with the approaches listed above, because the production css was not pointing to the compiled ttf font, so I then successfully used this alternative approach borrowed from https://gist.github.com/anotheruiguy/7379570:

1. Places all font files in `assets/stylesheets/fonts`. e.g. `assets/stylesheets/fonts/digital_7.ttf`.
2. I defined in a .scss file that we use:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'Digital-7';
       src: asset-url('fonts/digital_7.ttf') format('truetype');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
   }
   ```
3. I leveraged the custom font in other .scss files:

   ```
   .digital-font {
       font-family: 'Digital-7', sans-serif;
       font-size: 40px;
   }
   ```

---

This said, a much cleaner way of doing this is to put the font definition (digital_7_mono.ttf in this example) on a separate site.

If you are using Cloudfront, for example, in a Cloudfront directory called `my_path`, upload your font files, then define a css file (e.g. `digital_fonts.css`)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Digital-7-Mono';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Digital 7 Mono'), local('Digital-7-Mono'), url('https://mycloudfront_site.com/my_path/digital_7_mono.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

In your html, inside the `<head>` tag, add:

Answer (score 1):

The only way that worked for me was this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Vorname';
  src: asset-url('Vorname.otf') format('truetype'),
       asset-url('Vorname.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put fonts under `app/assets/fonts`, and modify url('Your Font Path') to font-url('Your Font Path') in your scss. Aslo Asset Pipeline will auto precompile fonts into `public/assests` folder.

check here for more detail:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass