# While Converting pdf.erb file to pdf using wicked pdf in rails 4.2, custom fonts are not working?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I am converting the html to PDF using wicked PDF tool . in that conversion custom font is not working.

Comment: please include examples of your views and source-code. (edit the question to add in the extra detail)

Answer (score 0):

From: [using custom (urdu) font in wicked-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012871/using-custom-urdu-font-in-wicked-pdf)

I have tried using wicked pdf asset based and its working fine.

```
url('<%= wicked_pdf_asset_base64('yourfile.ttf') %>')
```