# Rails 4 Font is not loading in SCSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know this is old question but I have been digging my head from many hours. Gone through all the links of SO but still unable to resolve this issue.

My fonts are in fonts directory which is present in assets directory. If i try to use `asset-url` it give me error saying Barrio font not found while my fonts is in the directory.

```
# application.rb
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
config.assets.precompile += %w( .otf )

# style.scss
@font-face {
  font-family: "Barrio-Regular";
  src: asset-url("Barrio-Regular.otf");
}

.catagories-list {
  label {
    font-family: "Barrio-Regular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  li {
    a {
      color: #2c2c2c;
    }
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    &.active a {
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: #2f2993;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the font-url helper

Comment: @Iceman AFAIK in Rails 4 there's no more font-url or it's deprecated.

Comment: Can you please paste whole error message?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error will be caused by this line:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

How will this handle if your app is precompiling the assets (where all the assets get put in the `public` folder)?

---

We typically do this:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/layout/fonts.css.sass
@font-face
    font:
        family: 'Ionicons'
        weight: normal
        style: normal
    src: asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.eot?v=1.4.1')
    src: asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.eot?v=1.4.1#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.ttf?v=1.4.1') format('truetype'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.woff?v=1.4.1') format('woff'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.svg?v=1.4.1#Ionicons') format('svg')
```

Basically, putting all our fonts in the `#app/assets/stylesheets/layouts/fonts` directory

---

Having looked at [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline) [resources](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/239), I would recommend this:

> With the fonts placed in app/assets/fonts/, you will NOT need to add
>   or edit anything in application.rb, production.rb or staging.rb.

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Barrio-Regular'
    src: asset_url('Barrio-Regular.otf')
}
```

If you do that without altering your `application.rb`, please come back with what the system responds with