# adding fonts to precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I add a assets/fonts folder to precompile?

I currently have the following:

```
  config.assets.precompile += %w( saas_admin.css saas_admin.js stripe_form.js fonts)
```

which isn't working, am I supposed to put assets/fonts instead?

**mystyle.css.erb**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular';
    src: url('SourceSansPro-Regular.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('SourceSansPro-Regular.otf')  format('opentype'),
         url('SourceSansPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('SourceSansPro-Regular.svg#SourceSansPro-Regular') format('svg');
         font-weight: normal;
         font-style: normal;
}
@font-face{
    font-family: 'MyriadProRegular';
    src: url('myriadpro-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: local('?'), url('myriadpro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('myriadpro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('myriadpro-regular-webfont.svg#webfont8y9VojoZ') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: try this `config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/`

Comment: Thanks! Tried that along with:   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
and it still isn't precompiling :(

Comment: change capital letters to lowercase, `SourceSansPro-Regular` change to  `sourcesanspro-regular` http://stackoverflow.com/a/10907276/1297435

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/environments/production.rb` file, add the following line:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.eot *.woff *.ttf *.otf *.svg )
```

This will include all of your font files in the precompile process.

Then in your Sass file, use the `font-url` helper so that the fonts works correctly with the asset pipeline. This will look inside of of `vendor/assets/fonts` or `app/assets/fonts` for your font files.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular';
    src: font-url('SourceSansPro-Regular.eot?') format('eot'),
         font-url('SourceSansPro-Regular.otf')  format('opentype'),
         font-url('SourceSansPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         font-url('SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         font-url('SourceSansPro-Regular.svg#SourceSansPro-Regular') format('svg');
         font-weight: normal;
         font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We use this on Heroku & it works - slightly different to `@jcypret`'s answer, but hopefully it will help:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += ["layout/fonts/fonts.css"] #-> you won't need this
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )

#app/assets/stylesheets/layout/fonts/fonts.css.sass (this is where we store our file...)
@font-face
    font:
        family: 'Ionicons'
        weight: normal
        style: normal
    src: asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.eot?v=1.4.1')
    src: asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.eot?v=1.4.1#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.ttf?v=1.4.1') format('truetype'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.woff?v=1.4.1') format('woff'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.svg?v=1.4.1#Ionicons') format('svg')
```

---

[**asset_url**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url)

Notice how we used the [`asset_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url) path?

I know one of the answers recommended the use of `fonts-url`, but we prefer to use `asset_url` (more reliable).

The main problem you'll generally have with fonts, esp on Heroku, is the [asset fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) (referencing `url: file` will only keep the static file). You need to be able to reference the dynamically generated file, which is where `asset_url` comes in

If you try this, it *should* work