# Rails 4 - Custom Fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, font-face

Currently I trying to add custom fonts into my Rails 4 application.

1. I added all of my fonts into `assets/fonts`
2. I added `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")` into `config/application.rb`
3. I added script into my `style.css`

```css
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'oxygenregular';
      src: url(font-path('oxygen-regular-webfont.eot') + "?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
           url(font-path('oxygen-regular-webfont.woff')) format('woff'), 
           url(font-path('oxygen-regular-webfont.ttf'))  format('truetype'),
           url(font-path('oxygen-regular-webfont.svg') + "#MyFont") format('svg');
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'oxygenregular', arial;
    background: #f4f5f9;
    background-image: url(../images/bg-pattern.png);
    background-position: 0 bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

I don't get any error like `404 (Not Found)`, since I got the error before modified `config/application.rb`

But the application doesn't load the font that I already put. I tried on native HTML and the fonts are working well, but when I trying to put them into Rails application, it doesn't load.a

Comment: Sub-question: Is doing `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/` enough, or do you also need to add paths?

Answer (score 2):

**Fonts**

The problem you have is you're calling the font files without referencing their paths correctly.

The issue here is the same as when you reference images or other files from the asset pipeline - if you use a file path which doesn't exist, it's just not going to load (because of the [asset fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)):

> Fingerprinting is a technique that makes the name of a file dependent
>   on the contents of the file. When the file contents change, the
>   filename is also changed. For content that is static or infrequently
>   changed, this provides an easy way to tell whether two versions of a
>   file are identical, even across different servers or deployment dates.

What you get with many Rails assets is an inability to reference the correct file, as the filepath has had its name changed when you `precompiled` them, preventing them from loading in *most* cases.

---

**Paths**

To add to `@praszyk`'s answer is that you'll need to use one of the `asset_paths` to pull the correct font path, which can be done using one of the [CSS preprocessors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) that come with Rails (typically `SCSS` or `SASS`)

The problem you have is using `.css` is not going to do this - you *have* to use either `.scss` or `.sass`:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/style.css.scss
@font-face { font-family: 'oxygenregular'; 
             src: asset_url('/fonts/oxygen-regular-webfont.eot' + "?#iefix") 
             format('embedded-opentype'), 
               asset_url('/fonts/oxygen-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
               asset_url('/fonts/oxygen-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
               asset_url(font-path('/fonts/oxygen-regular-webfont.svg') + "#MyFont") format('svg'); }
```

Using `asset_url` with `scss` will automatically call the correct version of the file - fingerprinted or not.

If you use this with `@praszyk`'s answer, it *should* hopefully work

Comment: I tried with ```@praszyk``` and your ways, but it still doesn't work. I changed ```style.css``` into ```style.css.scss``` and change the code like yours.

Comment: If you are using sass, `asset-url` with a hyphen rather than `asset_url` with an underscore is preferable. The former is sass, while the latter is rails (correct me if I'm wrong on this). Additionally, instead of `asset-url` there is a helper method `font-url` which is a bit more semantic. When using font-url, it will search in the /assets/fonts/ folder, just like how `image-url` searches the /assets/images/ folder. Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10907276/2951835

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'oxygenregular'; 
             src: url(font-path('/fonts/oxygen-regular-webfont.eot') + "?#iefix") 
             format('embedded-opentype'), 
             url(font-path('/fonts/oxygen-regular-webfont.woff')) format('woff'),
             url(font-path('/fonts/oxygen-regular-webfont.ttf')) format('truetype'), 
             url(font-path('/fonts/oxygen-regular-webfont.svg') + "#MyFont") format('svg'); }

body { font-family: 'oxygenregular', ...}
```

Since you're loading the fonts in "style.css" which resides in /assets/stylesheets (and /stylesheets/ in the browser) the script tries to load /stylesheets/oxygen-regular-webfont.eot.

Appending "/fonts/" to your paths should work as expected.
Also check the developer console of your browser if you're still having errors.

Comment: ```@praszyk``` I tried to change the code like yours, but it still doesn't work. Is it better if I put the code on ```assets/stylesheet/application.css``` ?

Comment: Did you add /fonts/ to your asset pipeline?

Comment: Can you make any folder under assets, and then a magic method "foldername-path" will appear? Is that how "font-path" can be called, even if it's not in the documentation?