# Using fonts with Rails 4.2.4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, sass, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to use a particular font in a Rails 4.2.4 app and nothing is working--it stubbornly refuses to show up.  I've spent a few hours on it, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The font is located at `app/assets/fonts/comic_andy.tff`.

SCSS (located at `app/assets/stylesheets/sass/application.css.scss`):

```
@font-face { 
font-family: "comic_andy"; 
src: font-url('comic_andy.ttf');
src: font-url('comic_andy.ttf'), format('truetype'); 
}
```

In the browser, the SCSS compiles to this CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "comic_andy";
src: url(/fonts/comic_andy.ttf);
src: url(/fonts/comic_andy.ttf), format("truetype");
}
```

Isn't it supposed to be compiling to assets/comic_andy.ttf?  I'm newer to Rails and although I get what the asset pipeline *is*, it's still proving tricky to wrap my head around enough to use very efficiently.

I've read through [Rails 4 - Custom Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731752/rails-4-custom-fonts), [How to use fonts in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294150/how-to-use-fonts-in-rails-4) and several other Stack Overflow questions related to fonts/Rails/the asset pipeline, and tried many of the suggestions, including (but not limited to!) adding `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')` to `application.rb` (nope), trying `asset-url` (nope), `font-url` (nope), and plain `url` (nope), and restarting the server several times after `rake assets:clobber` (nope). :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Don't change the assets path

If you put your resources into `app/assets`, you're all set, as mentioned [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#search-paths).

> The default locations are: the images, javascripts and stylesheets directories under the app/assets folder, but these subdirectories are not special - any path under assets/* will be searched.

#### Use `asset-url` or `font-url`

If you refer to [The Asset Pipeline page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) on Ruby on Rails guides, you'll see the adequate method here is to use `asset-url` (or `font-url`) as in:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'comic_andy';
    src: asset-url('comic_andy.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

On your development environment, it should compile as:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'comic_andy';
    src: url(/assets/comic_andy.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

NB: the proper format for .ttf files is `format("truetype")`.

#### Make sure your font format is supported

If things still don't work, maybe there's a problem with your ttf file (my project is using the `woff` format) and you should maybe use a service such as [Font Squirrel Webfont generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to fix it.

Comment: Except that I've tried that, and I've just tried again (after restarting the server)--and it's still not working.

Comment: Did you inspect things in your browser to see if the resource was missing (1) or was not used by the browser (2)?

Comment: I didn't--but now we're getting somewhere (maybe).  I'm getting this in the console: `GET 
http://localhost:3000/comic_andy.ttf [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  296ms]` as well as: 
`downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "comic_andy" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:3000/comic_andy.ttf`

Comment: It's weird that you don't compile as 'assets/comic_andy.ttf'. On a sidenote, it seems like you should use `format('truetype');` instead of `format('ttf');`. I would remove any config you added to `config.assets.paths`, restart your app and see what it does.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you went out of your way to help. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, finally.  F I N A L L Y.

The SASS:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: "comic_andy"; 
    src: font-url('comicandy.ttf');
    src: font-url('comicandy.ttf'), format("truetype"); }
```

Application.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Asshat Pipeline wasn't compiling the SASS correctly, because I was missing `config.assets.enabled = true`.  Somewhere along the line, the font also got renamed.  I don't know why or how that helped solved the issue, but it appeared to somehow help solve the issue.