# NameError: undefined local variable or method `font' (asset pipeline)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts, asset-pipeline

I am trying to load some fonts that are in my Rails asset pipeline. They are located in 
assets/fonts/. I have tried following this SO article to emulate the Poster's steps: [Using fonts with Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline).

I added this to `application.rb`: `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")`

and I have the following statements in my `application.html.erb` layout file.

```
@font-face{
  font-family:"Apollo MT W02 Italic";
  src:url(<%=asset_path('fonty.eot?#iefix',font)%>);
  src:url(<%=asset_path('fonty.eot?#iefix',font)%>)   format("eot"),url(<%=asset_path("fonty.woff",font)%>) format("woff"),url(<%=asset_path("fonty.ttf",font)%>)   format("truetype"),url(<%=asset_path("fonty.svg#fonty",font)%>) format("svg");
}
```

When I go to the homepage of my app I get this this error:

```
NameError in Welcome#index
undefined local variable or method `font' for #<#<Class:0x0000010477c108>:0x00000106f08208>
```

which is being thrown at this line:

```
    src:url(<%=asset_path('fonty.eot?#iefix',font)%>);
```

Comment: it looks like you aren't defining `font` anywhere. What are you trying to pass in to the url?

Comment: I am trying to pass in the `assets/fonts/fonty.tfff` path relative to my root.