# Failed to load resource: 404 (Not Found) - Rails custom fonts

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, fonts, assets

I am trying to load some custom fonts via the CSS `@font-face`. I am using the rails `fonts_path` method. It succesfully generates the correct path in my development browser:

```
/assets/fonts/my_font.eot?#iefix
```

However it appends this path to `0.0.0.0:3000` (rails Development server) which *may not be the location of /assets/fonts/* in my Rails project. I don't know the relationship between routes that are routed by Rails and things like Rails assets.

Here is the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/fonts/my_Ffent.woff
```

Here is my stylesheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face{
  font-family:"My Font";
  src:url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/my_font.eot?#iefix')%>);
  src:url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/my_font.eot?#iefix')%>) format("eot"),url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/my_font.woff')%>) format("woff"),url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/my_font.ttf')%>) format("truetype"),url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/my_font.svg#c1b10d74-5304-41c3-b9de-00f29187df91')%>) format("svg");
}
</style>
```

The stylesheet is placed in `application.html.erb` which may be part of the problem? It is defined in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: have you tried the solutions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Looked through my code where ive used @font-face and ive documented it this way. Give it a try and see if it works for you. 
As you can see ive declared the font src localy by just declaring its name.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yourfont Novum Light';
    src: local('yourfont Novum Light') url("https://cns.xx.com/ux/site/1.1/fonts/yourfont-novum/yourfont-Novum-Light.eot");

font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal
```

}