# Third Party Font Integration Ruby on Rails Not Working Path Ok, Naming Good, Compiled No Errors in console or server

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts

**Updated**

Now this is what my application.scss looks like now

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DidotLTStd-Roman';
  src: font-url('2C0947_0_0.eot') format("embedded-opentype");
  src: font-url('2C0947_0_0.woff') format('woff');
  src: font-url('2C0947_0_0.ttf') format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'DidotLTStd-Italic';
  src: font-url('2C0947_1_0.eot') format("embedded-opentype");
  src: font-url('2C0947_1_0.woff') format('woff');
  src: font-url('2C0947_1_0.ttf') format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'AvantGardeGothicITCW02XLt';
  src: font-url('2C0947_2_0.eot') format("embedded-opentype");
  src: font-url('2C0947_2_0.woff') format('woff');
  src: font-url('2C0947_2_0.ttf') format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}


.about {
    font-family: 'AvantGardeGothicITCW02XLt';
}
```

including this line in application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

but still not working. No problems in chrome console and I doublechecked the file names.

---

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/webfonts/2C0947_1_0.ttf"):

Its my first time integration third party fonts in the ruby on rails application. I am going the directions here in the corrected answer

[Using fonts with Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline)

Its a rails 4.0.2 app.
I dropped all of my eot, ttf, woff fonts into the app/assets/fonts folder

by default since this is a 4.0.2 app it should look at this fonts folder

I am using scss.

I added the following to my application.scss file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DidotLTStd-Roman';
  src:url('2C0947_0_0.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'DidotLTStd-Italic';
  src:url('2C09047_1_0.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'AvantGardeGothicITCW02XLt';
  src:url('2C09047_2_0.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.about {
    font-family: 'DidotLTStd-Italic';
}
```

I have alternate the `src:font-url to src:url` 
I have tried adding this to application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

I have restarted the server. This is what I see when I check in the console log

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/2C09047_1_0.woff
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/webfonts/2C0947_1_0.woff
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/webfonts/2C0947_1_0.ttf
```

its looking for the webfonts folder and I even changed the name of the fonts folder to webfonts but it still couldn't find it.

So the zip folder that I bought also contain a layout.css and a mywebfontkit.css which I drop into the stylesheets folder inside assets. I also dropped the highlight.js into the js assets folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `application.rb`

```
# Precompile additional assets - from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

Also, FYI, it was the `font-url` version that worked for me - like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'interstate-boldcondensedbold';
  src: font-url("interstate-boldcondensed-webfont.eot");
  src: font-url("interstate-boldcondensed-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), font-url("interstate-boldcondensed-webfont.woff") format("woff"), font-url("interstate-boldcondensed-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), font-url("interstate-boldcondensed-webfont.svg#interstate-boldcondensedbold") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

(And don't forget to restart the server again afterwards!)

Comment: I definitely see improvements. But now I am getting `GET http://localhost:3000/fonts/2C09047_1_0.woff ` problem in chrome console. I switched to `font-url` as well. It improved because its now looking at the right place but it can't find it even though the woff file is there. Also the search to `/assets/webfonts` did not go away. I tried this version as well `config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/`