# Fonts in rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts

I want to make a rails application with the 'Mostly Mono' font ("http://www.1001fonts.com/mostlymono-font.html"), and I tried the asset pipeline method the says here [Using fonts with Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline) .

I placed this in config/application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

And this to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MostlyMono';
src: font-url('/assets/fonts/mostlymono.ttf') format('truetype'); }
```

Is there any other method or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you download the fonts and add them to your directory?

Comment: Yes I did, but I just have one archive called "mostlymono.medium.tff", I don't know if I just need that one or I need more archives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom fonts bellow way -

1. Create a folder name "fonts" inside the app/assets directory and place mostlymono.ttf fonts inside the fonts directory.
2. Now add this line to config/application.rb

   ```
   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
   ```
3. Now you have to rename app/assets/stylesheets/application.css to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss and place to bellow code-

   ```
   @font-face {
    font-family: "MostlyMono";
    src: url(asset-path("mostlymono.ttf")) format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
   }
   ```
4. Now add fonts to config/initializers/assets.rb for Precompile additional assets.

   ```
   Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( mostlymono.ttf )
   ```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work, but I got three points:
1.- font-family: "Ionicons" is ok? Shouldn't I put MostlyMono?
2.- I downloaded the font and placed it in app/assets/fonts/, and it's called "mostlymono.medium.tff"
3.- Let's say it works, when I want to use the font I have to put it like

    .header{
    font-family: 'MostlyMono';
}

or like

    .header{
    font-family: '@font-face';
}