# Rails - using vendor fonts in vendor css in Rails 4 app - asset pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to adapt a wrap bootstrap theme for use in Rails 4.

The theme uses simple-line-icons. I've tried to move those files to a font folder in my app/assets folder as well as to the css file in my vendor/assets/css folder and the js folder in my vendor/assets/javascript folder.

I don't understand how to rewrite paths in the css so as to reference the assets in a way that will get rails to read them.

For example, one of the css files includes the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons';
  src: url("../../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot");
  src: url("../../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff") format("woff"), url("../../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.svg#Simple-Line-Icons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I understand that the url(../.. part is a problem for rails. What I can't figure out is how to solve it.

I have rails-12factor gem installed in my production environment. I've tried a million variations (shown in the rails guides), but I can't find anything that works.

Can anyone see what to do?

This article suggests not to include the 'fonts' folder in referencing vendor assets font files. https://gist.github.com/iamatypeofwalrus/6467148

I've tried including and excluding it but neither way works.

This article suggests that vendor file is not capable of storing fonts without amending the initialiser. I tried that but it doesnt work either.
[Using fonts with Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline?rq=1)

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths
 => ["/Users/cf3/app/assets/images", "/Users/cf3/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/cf3/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/cf3/vendor/assets/fonts", "/Users/cf3/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/cf3/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/underscore-rails-1.8.3/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/gmaps4rails-2.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/chosen-rails-1.4.3/vendor/assets/images", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/chosen-rails-1.4.3/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/chosen-rails-1.4.3/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/chartkick-1.4.1/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/formtastic-2.2.1/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/surveyor-5281b317a559/lib/assets/images", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/surveyor-5281b317a559/lib/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/surveyor-5281b317a559/lib/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/dependent-fields-rails-0.4.2/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoon-1.2.6/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.0.5/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/momentjs-rails-eda1b74512db/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-slider-rails-5.3.1/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-slider-rails-5.3.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "Rails/vendor/assets/fonts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/javascripts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/fonts", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/images", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.4.0/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/lem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.4.0/assets/fonts"]
```

**HEROKU**

I've now found this post, that suggests that for heroku compliance in production, I need to replace everything with asset path helpers and rename the files to add .erb to images and css and .coffee to js. Before I do this, can someone please confirm this is actually required, and how I would go about changing the above css file to comply with heroku requirements.

http://joanswork.com/wrapbootstrap-theme-to-rails/

Comment: Put these files to app/assets directory and you can access them with path `src: url("/assets/Simple-Line-Icons.eot");`

Comment: No, there are vendor css files and vendor js files, so i need to keep them together. I've tried vendor/assets/fonts but it isn't working

Answer (score 6):

> Actually any sub-directory added to `assets` directory is auto added to the load
>   paths. Files in those directories can be accessed as normal asset
>   files.
>
> If you have
>
> ```
> vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot
> ```
>
> then vendor/assets/fonts/ should be added to load paths.

Then you can add all font files to your css files with path : `font/file_name`

Remember to restart your server after this as load paths will reload after restarting the server.

You can see the list of load paths through `rails console` by following command :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths
```

You can add new load paths by following command :

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "fonts")
OR to autoload : config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "fonts")
```

Comment: Neither vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons nor vendor/assets/Simple-Line-Icons works. I don't know what you mean about font/file_name. The example above shows how it is used in the css files (with src url). My console inspector shows 404 errors both ways

Comment: Run this `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in your rails console and paste the output here.

Comment: `src: url("/assets/Simple-Line-Icons.eot");` should work!

Comment: copied and added above   .

Comment: I've got it in vendor assets fonts folders

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline?rq=1

Comment: Yes - that is the post i copied in my question above. I've tried its suggestions. It doesnt work

Comment: you added this `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "fonts")` to your application.rb and restarted the server ?

Comment: For heroku precompile assets on local and push them to heroku. `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: I've tried that at least 10 times. It doesnt work. In any event i use rails 12 factor gem which is supposed to replace the need for that