# Bootstrap with Rails without LESS/SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a project of Rails 4 integrated with bootstrap.
I use [less-rails-bootstrap](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap) gem in order to integrate it.

I wonder what is the best way to integrate bootstrap into rails without using less (os sass). I assume I can simply download the css and js files [as explained in the bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), but I wonder if i might have problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you don't want to customize Bootstrap styles, you can simply download it from bootstrap site and put it under `vendor` folder.

And you won't have problems, since Rails will precompile the files (js/css/img) under `vendor` folder.

[Make sure to read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10907276/740394) if you add fonts too.