# Rails fonts were not precompiled for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got some fonts added in the app/assets/fonts

they do not precompile for production ...

tried this in application.rb

```
module app
   class Application < Rails::Application

      config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts", "tinymce")
```

whats going wrong?

I'm Using rails 4.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using fonts with Rails asset pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline)

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question with more information.  For example: What is your target environment?  Are you just issuing a local assets:precompile?  What are you expecting and what are you seeing, exactly?  That way, we can see what might be wrong and best advise you.  Beyond that, there are already excellent SO answers around this question, so a search would help.  Good luck!

Comment: my target environment should be the production! ... Problem is that the fonts which are located under app/assets/fonts not precompiled. I see the normal page but wrong fonts an fontawesome not working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside assets.paths you need to put assets.precompile in your application.rb:
For example:

```
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```

Comment: Do you use the tinymce-rails gem?
https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails#asset-compilation

Comment: no why? --- in my example tinymce isn't important it works fine ... 

I've got only problems with the fonts