# web fonts not loading through asset pipeline in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to load some webfonts from myfonts.com into my rails application running on DigitalOcean.  It seems to work precompile just fine and it works locally in 'development' mode but doesn't load the files in 'production' mode.

Other answers to these problems point to the asset pipeline but the solutions don't help.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
app
|assets
||fonts
|||*various font files*
```

main.scss

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/30b86b");


@font-face {
    font-family: 'SofiaProExtraLight';
    src: asset-url('30B86B_0_0.eot');
    src: asset-url('30B86B_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),asset-url('30B86B_0_0.woff2') format('woff2'),asset-url('30B86B_0_0.woff') format('woff'),asset-url('30B86B_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'SofiaProSemiBold';
    src: asset-url('30B86B_1_0.eot');
    src: asset-url('30B86B_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),asset-url('30B86B_1_0.woff2') format('woff2'),asset-url('30B86B_1_0.woff') format('woff'),asset-url('30B86B_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'SofiaProRegular';
    src: asset-url('30B86B_2_0.eot');
    src: asset-url('30B86B_2_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),asset-url('30B86B_2_0.woff2') format('woff2'),asset-url('30B86B_2_0.woff') format('woff'),asset-url('30B86B_2_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using fonts with Rails asset pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this into your `application.rb`:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...
    config.assets.paths += %w(fonts)
  end
end
```

Comment: You fixed it so easily and I hate that I didn't come to SA earlier. Thank you