# fonts issue in productions envirnment rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I made an rails (4.2.4) app which work fine in development environment but when I deployed it on digital ocean it doesn't get fonts, with an error like

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

with path like

```
http://Server-IP/assets/raleway-bold.woff2
```

I tried many combinations to provide path but all in vain except one, which works in development  but not in production.

I have little different structure for assets

```
assets
    - fonts
    - javascripts
    - stylesheets
               - admin
               - web
                    - application.js
                    - fonts.cs

               - application.cs
```

and in fonts.cs I am providing path like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dpdidot_htfm96medium';
    src:  url('/assets/dp_didot-htf-m96-medium-webfont.eot');
    src:  url('/assets/dp_didot-htf-m96-medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('/assets/dp_didot-htf-m96-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('/assets/dp_didot-htf-m96-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
          url('/assets/dp_didot-htf-m96-medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
          url('/assets/dp_didot-htf-m96-medium-webfont.svg#dpdidot_htfm96medium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Whats wrong with it

Comment: I think the location of assets in development and production are different

Comment: Have you run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: @EdwinLunando yes I precompiled them

Comment: @Lymuel
I didn't get what are try to say, elaborate please

Comment: could you show us your `assets.rb`?

Comment: @EdwinLunando
in config/tantalizer/assets.rb all commented line except this one , Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

Comment: I mean the path where the assets is different if you are in production, try to change the value of `config.assets.compile` on your **production.rb** to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The default precompiling assets with Rails will only generate `application.js` and `application.css`. If you want the precompile generate unpacked assets like the fonts, add it to the `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` this is the example. You can add this to `assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['*.js', '*.css', '*.woff2', '*.woff']
```

Comment: I didn't get it
Is the line line which I have to add in some file with extensions?
If yes where to add it

Comment: Add it at the last. Put it in the `assets.rb`

Comment: Don't know what happened but now its giving error while deploying, "Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding".
"

Comment: There are something wrong on your sass file. You need to fix it. :)

Comment: Actually the line "Rails.application.config.assets.precompile" is causing the issue,  its compiling everything with .css extension, even bootstrap files too.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/654

Comment: but there is another thing. when I deployed it without adding line to assets.rb , site runs but says "not found for fonts" but when I click on the path it gives for not found, It open the file, weird, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, by default, Rails precompiling every assets file. You can remove `*.js` and `*.css` if you need to.