# Rails assets is having issues with my fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Both locally and in heroku I am having issues with my fonts.

Rails 4.2.5.1

My fonts are in the app/fonts folder:

```
/app/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
/app/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
/app/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
/app/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
/app/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.otf
```

The error message:

```
Started GET "/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0" for ::1 at 2016-06-01 22:12:24 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"):
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
```

config/initializers/assets.rb has:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '2.0'
```

What could the issue be here, very confused?

Comment: How are you including your fonts? When do you get this error?

Comment: My fonts are referenced in the font-awesome.min.css file, I changed all references to be /assets/fonts/...

Answer (score 4):

Although Rails has you store your assets in `assets/javascripts`, `assets/stylesheets`, `assets/fonts`, or whatever, those directories do not map directly to URLs. Instead everything is served from just `/assets`. So in your browser's location bar type http://localhost:3000/assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf and I bet you'll get the font.

So you should find whatever is referencing the font, and fix the URL there (probably in a CSS file). **BUT** note that in production Rails also mangles the names of these assets to make them more cachable, so the correct URL in production will be something like http://example.com/assets/fontawesome-webfont-asdfasasdfadsfadfsasf23kjksdjkasdfadsf.ttf. You can make sure you always get the right URL by using the [asset_path helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path). There is also `asset_url`, `image_path`, etc. There is even `font_path`!

Comment: so I should use font_path in my stylesheet, I have to rename it from .css to .scss to use font_path right?

Comment: Will something like this work?  ```font_url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0')``` ?  seems to be complaining about a bad URI

Comment: I would leave out the query parameter part and just say `font_url('fontawesome-webfont.eot')`. Also is this an scss file? In that case it should be `font-url` (hyphen not underscore). Or if it's an erb file then you need to surround the helper in erb tags: `<%= font_url('...') %>`.

Comment: Also here is a very thorough answer about using fonts in scss files in Rails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

The `fonts` folder is not loaded along with the other Rails asset pipeline folders in the asset so pipeline so you need to first add it to it.

In your `config/application.rb` file add this line:

`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")`

inside the Application class like this

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
end
```

this will allow the `font` folder to be loaded on application start along with the remaining folders

then in your css file, change all `src: url("/assets/fonts/font_name.format");` to `src: url("/assets/font_name.format");`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the font awesome css from my project and just added the [darn gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) and it works :)