# Ruby On Rails & Flaticon => How to import (using Icon Fonts) Flaticon Icons in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I'm trying to import icons from Flaticon in my Rails app. They have a small tutorial for basic website (only HTML + CSS) but I can't integrate it into my app rails.

I don't want to import them as classic picture but as elements `<i class></i>` (like Font Awesome) in order to be able to modify the style in css later.

The tutorial => https://www.flaticon.com/iconfonts

The Key question for me is where I must put the Flaticon files in my rails app? In stylesheets?

For now, I only succeeded to have little square, instead of icons.

Have someone here already used Flaticon Icon Fonts tutorial to import custom icons in his Rails app ?

Thanks in Advance ;)

Matt from Paris

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the followings.

1. add flaticon font files (eot, ttf, svg, woff) to `vendor/assets/fonts`
2. configure asset pipepline to use fonts
3. add flaticon css file to `vendor/assets/stylesheets`
4. import flaticon css in `application.{scss|sass|css}`
5. restart server

Details for above two steps can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10907276/188574).

If it still doesn't work you have to look into the flatfile css file (for reference of font-file by path).

And you should read [Rails Guide Asset Pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it runs !