# Rails 4.1.4 tries to connect to uninitialized Mongo database when pushing to Heroku (rake assets:precompile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, heroku, mongoid

I'm aware that there are some other questions related to this issue, but I haven't been able to find an answer yet.

I'm building an app with **Rails 4.1.4**. I'm using **MongoDB** as my database and **Mongoid 4.0.0** as ODM.

When I push my app to **Heroku**, the build fails when running **rake assets:precompile** because **Rails** tries to connect to the production database, which is not initialized at this point, and defaults connecting to the development database, which does not exist in production. This is the error I get:

> > Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
> >            Running: rake assets:precompile
> >            rake aborted!
> >            Mongo::ConnectionFailure: Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.10.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:422:in
> >     `connect'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.10.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:661:in`
> >     setup'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.10.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:177:in
> >     `initialize'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.0/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:88:in`
> >     new'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.0/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:88:in
> >     `connect'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.0/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:98:in`
> >     setup'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.0/lib/mongo_mapper/railtie.rb:48:in
> >     `block in <class:Railtie>'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
> >     instance_exec'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
> >     `run'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`
> >     block in run_initializers'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
> >     `run_initializers'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in`
> >     initialize!'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/config/environment.rb:5:in
> >     `<top (required)>'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in`
> >     require'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in
> >     `require_environment!'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in`
> >     block in run_tasks_blocks'
> >            /tmp/build_f8b818f9-3058-4ea1-807e-158e2964efcd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in
> >     `block (2 levels) in define'
> >            Tasks: TOP => environment
> >            (See full trace by running task with --trace)  !  !     Precompiling assets failed.  !
>
> !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Does anyone knows a fix for this issue?. How can I tell **Rails** to not connect to the databse while precompiling assets in the production environment?.

Thanks in advance for any help!.

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ISSUE SOLVED**. **Rails 4.1.4** has no problem with what I've stated. I was doing something wrong, my bad!.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try enabling the labs feature to have the environment available on precompile:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

Others [seem to be having success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775844/unicorn-triggers-mongoid-error-during-assets-precompile) doing that in similar situations.

Comment: That feature is not longer available in Heroku. Heroku now enables it by default. So that fix won't work for me. Thanks anyways!.