# Asset Procompile Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am deploying my app to Rackspace using Capistrano, and I'm receiving the following error during: assets:precompile

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "    filter: progid": expected ";", was ": DXImageTransf..."
```

I have searched all over my project for "    filter: progid", but it is no where to be found. Where could this be coming from? I've also tried debugging the asset pipeline by using the first answer to this question:
[How to debug a Rails asset precompile which is unbearably slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325039/how-to-debug-a-rails-asset-precompile-which-is-unbearably-slow)

But no more details are being shown in the log. What is going on and what is a good way to debug this?

Here is more from the deploy log:

```
INFO [64e3ce61] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deployer@162.242.239.118
DEBUG [64e3ce61] Command: cd /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327 && ( RVM_BIN_PATH=~/.rvm/bin RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.070565 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/anthem-default-39b0d92434994ac099900eec485cc9f2.png
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.073050 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/bear-e1d6322cce5569e1c88e51d726af8f49.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.075270 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/boar-69a6591e2ba09c0425c26384111500f5.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.077679 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/buck-31c081b201e23e3a00bc29cb128d5fd4.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.080081 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/bull-3846b82866f1ffc43579c9dbbaea959b.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.082582 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/deer1-53930494d0c237140ab4ff7bf79e7c7d.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.084997 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/elephant-3a6488b5a50b6028ade84121e092a8dd.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.087469 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/elk-4e0e97aaef000861f86f5ca73c51be65.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.089586 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/gazelle-e0df179137756577b495d7e277f08872.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.091062 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/img/ComingSoon-9e6e4ed60f2e59559bd2233c4b927cca.png
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.092389 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/img/Logo-Tag-Web-f5a783606998baef9dd6a9a9da918b00.png
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.093541 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/img/Logo-Web-bf5f817803fe5049dcc17e40edec18ce.png
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.094571 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/img/Updates-55abc0feec2e660fe0f5bf75a2678166.png
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.095679 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/img/favicon-e81ee536c6ccbbac5ebaa55cbd76a2f8.ico
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.096726 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/img/main-iphone-s-0a962d3e5f6e771531bb233ce96639dc.png
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.100177 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/img/main-iphone1-956bf0a15b26580db3b0cde8a1104570.png
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.102770 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/img/main-iphone2-0aad36bdc116feb50d4126aadd396d25.png
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.103968 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/img/submit-bd907ae0ff6d7fcbf954a5dac6bdbc3f.png
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.105949 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/ram-7cbd47fc46d2416b1f0c1fd18ae9054f.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.108138 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/rhino-94a138284b456294d35e2251b5abbef7.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.110673 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/walrus-f3aa57e0ef921235433fee20ce5e1ba8.jpg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.119501 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/admin/index-4256726c6aa749d8d3928d41b258f9cf.js
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.132553 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/angular/templates/anthems/show-c660570a856e7f7a9d39e2e1bb771f58.htm
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.136067 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/angular/templates/home/index-774f715c201e85617e6cc204ba9f6a49.htm
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.138598 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/angular/templates/shared/footer-8b0a438e07297554d78ff80372378ea7.htm
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.204682 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/application-938b87f951fd4616fddd60fab4e78a4a.js
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.227899 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-050f85c5fbaa79689431c2a1f211fe2a.eot
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.229897 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-3c8f142df5ab3046bbeb3c3310ae4fa9.svg
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.231285 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-632d47971ce98f67252b59ec394cb688.ttf
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.232743 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-e88ed3ff660b39de62652ed99f351552.woff
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.233944 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-b5493d564382942c09f766d4c2b51f0a.woff2
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    I, [2015-02-24T07:03:08.242715 #14299]  INFO -- : Writing /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/public/assets/admin/index-c38398b732f9e0c66a527c570ac837d2.css
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "    filter: progid": expected ";", was ": DXImageTransf..."
DEBUG [64e3ce61]      (in /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/releases/20150224070327/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    (sass):14481
DEBUG [64e3ce61]    /usr/share/nginx/www/anthem.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1149:in `expected'
```

Comment: can you please provide whole error with line number file name `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Can you put the same line, where you were getting compilation error

Comment: Please search "DXImageTransf" in /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css then please paste the line as well

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong in my case previously:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='$color1')
```

Then What I did to resolve it:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="$color1")
```

Try double quotes "$color"

Answer (score 0):

You might try searching for `DXImageTransf`, instead, to get you to the offending line. Basically, you've probably just got some bad syntax somewhere in there. I find the best way to "debug" these issues is to not get into them in the first place, by using a full-featured IDE with syntax awareness. I prefer [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), as it has a host of other great features as well (no affiliation, just a happy customer). It will show you both in the project tree view, and in the file editor itself where the errors lie.

Comment: I am in fact using RubyMine. Is there a way to search for project wide for all errors?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html For me, it shows me files with errors underlined with a squiggly line in the project tree view, and the editor has squiggly underlines as well as red boxes on the right side of "bad" lines.